# json_decodeがうまく機能しない　特定のJSONを取り出し連想配列にしたい。

Tags: php, laravel

$parentArrという配列があります。この中から特定のJSONの配列を取得し、連想配列にしたいのですがうまくいきません

```
print_r($parentArr );
```

結果↓

```
Array
(
[id] => 1
[company_id] => 2
[fruits] => {"apple": 4"peach": 2,"orange": 1}
);
```

ここから　fruits　を取り出し、$fruitArray = ['apple'=>4, 'peach'=>1, 'orange'=>1]としたい。

```
$fruitArray =json_decode($parentArr["fruits"],true);
print_r($fruitArray );
```

結果

何も表示されません。

Answer (score 0):

それはおかしいですね。下記のコードは期待どおりの結果になると思うので、何が違っているのか、比較してみてください。

```
<?php
$json = json_encode(array("apple" => 4, "peach" => 2, "orange" => 1));
$parentArr = array("id" => 1, "company_id" => 2, "fruits" => $json);
print_r($parentArr);
$fruitArray =json_decode($parentArr["fruits"], true);
print_r($fruitArray);
```

結果

Array
(
[id] => 1
[company_id] => 2
[fruits] => {"apple":4,"peach":2,"orange":1}
)
Array
(
[apple] => 4
[peach] => 2
[orange] => 1
)